# Array index is out of bounds while using bvp solver in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I am using the `bvp solver` in Python to simulate a 4th order boundary value problem, of the form `d4y/dx4= F(y)/(t-y)^2`, where `F(y)` is a complicated function of the variable `y`. The code that I have written for the same has been attached below :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
from numpy import arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

def xmesh(k1):
 return np.linspace(0,L,k1)

def solveit(gamma):
 def fun(x,y): # this function returns all the derivatives for the bvp solver
  m1=y[0] # m1 is an 1-D array
  array=np.empty(10,)
  def calc(): # this function calculates F(y) at all the mesh points and finally returns an array 
    for i in range(10) :
     def fun2(var):
       return gamma*(var)+var**(0.5)+var**(3)+m1[i]
       
     sol= root(fun2,x0=0.00001,method='krylov',tol=1e-12)  
     array[i]=sol.x
         
    return array   

  m2=calc() # m2 is an 1-D array and is equal to F(y)
  rhs= m2/((t-m1)**2) # rhs contains the RHS of the differential equation
  return np.vstack([y[1],y[2],y[3],rhs])
  
 def bc(ya,yb): # boundary conditions for the bvp solver
    return np.array([ya[0],ya[1],yb[0],yb[1]])
 q= 10
 yinit= np.zeros((4,len(xmesh(q))))
 sol= solve_bvp(fun,bc,xmesh(q),yinit,tol=1e-6,max_nodes=5000)
 arr= sol.sol(xmesh(q))[0] # array containing y
 return arr   
a=solveit(0.1)
```

Whenever I try to run the above code, I bump into the error : `index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9`. I don't understand why this error is raised. It means that the array has 9 elements and I am trying to refer to the 10th element of the array and hence it raises this error. But all the arrays defined in the code above have 10 elements each. So, I don't understand why this error is even being raised. I have been stuck with this for 2 days now. Any solution to the above problem will highly be appreciated.
**P.S.**- The functions that I have defined in the code above have no physical meaning and are completely random. So, I do not need a correct numerical solution to the above code. All I need is the code to work fine without any error. Also, I have previously used the bvp solver in Python with success.

***edit*** : I have added the stack trace.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8423177548fe> in <module>()
     34  arr= sol.sol(xmesh(q))[0] # array containing y
     35  return arr
---> 36 a=solveit(0.1)

12 frames
<ipython-input-4-8423177548fe> in solveit(gamma)
     31  q= 10
     32  yinit= np.zeros((4,len(xmesh(q))))
---> 33  sol= solve_bvp(fun,bc,xmesh(q),yinit,tol=1e-6,max_nodes=5000)
     34  arr= sol.sol(xmesh(q))[0] # array containing y
     35  return arr

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py in solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, p, S, fun_jac, bc_jac, tol, max_nodes, verbose, bc_tol)
   1084                                        fun_jac_wrapped, bc_jac_wrapped, x, h)
   1085         y, p, singular = solve_newton(n, m, h, col_fun, bc_wrapped, jac_sys,
-> 1086                                       y, p, B, tol, bc_tol)
   1087         iteration += 1
   1088 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py in solve_newton(n, m, h, col_fun, bc, jac, y, p, B, bvp_tol, bc_tol)
    439     n_trial = 4
    440 
--> 441     col_res, y_middle, f, f_middle = col_fun(y, p)
    442     bc_res = bc(y[:, 0], y[:, -1], p)
    443     res = np.hstack((col_res.ravel(order='F'), bc_res))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py in col_fun(y, p)
    324 
    325     def col_fun(y, p):
--> 326         return collocation_fun(fun, y, p, x, h)
    327 
    328     def sys_jac(y, p, y_middle, f, f_middle, bc0):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py in collocation_fun(fun, y, p, x, h)
    311     y_middle = (0.5 * (y[:, 1:] + y[:, :-1]) -
    312                 0.125 * h * (f[:, 1:] - f[:, :-1]))
--> 313     f_middle = fun(x[:-1] + 0.5 * h, y_middle, p)
    314     col_res = y[:, 1:] - y[:, :-1] - h / 6 * (f[:, :-1] + f[:, 1:] +
    315                                               4 * f_middle)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py in fun_p(x, y, _)
    648     if k == 0:
    649         def fun_p(x, y, _):
--> 650             return np.asarray(fun(x, y), dtype)
    651 
    652         def bc_wrapped(ya, yb, _):

<ipython-input-4-8423177548fe> in fun(x, y)
     23     return array
     24 
---> 25   m2=calc() # m2 is an 1-D array and is equal to F(y)
     26   rhs= m2/((t-m1)**2) # rhs contains the RHS of the differential equation
     27   return np.vstack([y[1],y[2],y[3],rhs])

<ipython-input-4-8423177548fe> in calc()
     18        return gamma*(var)+var**(0.5)+var**(3)+m1[i]
     19 
---> 20      sol= root(fun2,x0=0.00001,method='krylov',tol=1e-12)
     21      array[i]=sol.x
     22 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_root.py in root(fun, x0, args, method, jac, tol, callback, options)
    197         sol = _root_nonlin_solve(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac,
    198                                  _method=meth, _callback=callback,
--> 199                                  **options)
    200     else:
    201         raise ValueError('Unknown solver %s' % method)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_root.py in _root_nonlin_solve(func, x0, args, jac, _callback, _method, nit, disp, maxiter, ftol, fatol, xtol, xatol, tol_norm, line_search, jac_options, **unknown_options)
    300                                   line_search=line_search,
    301                                   callback=_callback, full_output=True,
--> 302                                   raise_exception=False)
    303     sol = OptimizeResult(x=x)
    304     sol.update(info)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/nonlin.py in nonlin_solve(F, x0, jacobian, iter, verbose, maxiter, f_tol, f_rtol, x_tol, x_rtol, tol_norm, line_search, callback, full_output, raise_exception)
    277 
    278     dx = np.inf
--> 279     Fx = func(x)
    280     Fx_norm = norm(Fx)
    281 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/nonlin.py in <lambda>(z)
    273 
    274     x0 = _as_inexact(x0)
--> 275     func = lambda z: _as_inexact(F(_array_like(z, x0))).flatten()
    276     x = x0.flatten()
    277 

<ipython-input-4-8423177548fe> in fun2(var)
     16     for i in range(10) :
     17      def fun2(var):
---> 18        return gamma*(var)+var**(0.5)+var**(3)+m1[i]
     19 
     20      sol= root(fun2,x0=0.00001,method='krylov',tol=1e-12)

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9
```

Comment: Please give the stack trace so that people can see where the error is happening.

Comment: @alaniwi, I havd added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

In the function

```
  def calc(): # this function calculates F(y) at all the mesh points and finally returns an array 
    for i in range(10) :
        def fun2(var):
            return gamma*(var)+var**(0.5)+var**(3)+m1[i]
```

you are iterating over `m1` inside the nested function with `i` but in the above code on the line

```
m1=y[0] # m1 is an 1-D array
```

you define this value as a scalar (or a 1D-array) which cannot be iterated over.

This gives you the error you are observing; for the 1D-array you have defined, `m1`, any index greater than `0` is out of range for this 1D-array.

This should give you what you need to change your code so that it works.

I won't complete this for you, because we don't know what you need done, but I expect that defining a function again and again in a for loop is unnecessary.

Comment: m1 is an 1d array of size 10 because y[0] is an 1d array of size 10.

Comment: And the error suggests that the array is of size 9 which is anyway greater than 0.